# XSLT copy element to another according to attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to copy a node according to an attribute in another node in the same element. An example input XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
    <Department id="Marketing">
        <depName>Marketing</depName>
        <position>Marketer</position>
    </Department>
    <Employee id="e1" level="l1">
        <First>John</First>
        <Dep code="Marketing"></Dep>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="e2" level="l1">
        <First>Jane</First>
        <Dep code="Marketing"></Dep>
    </Employee>
    <Boss id="e3" level="l2">
        <First>Ben</First>
        <Dep code="Marketing"></Dep>
    </Boss>
</Company>
```

The output XML should look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
    <Department id="Marketing">
        <depName>Marketing</depName>
        <position>Marketer</position>
    </Department>
    <Employee id="e1" level="l1">
        <First>John</First>
        <Dep code="Marketing"></Dep>
        <position>Marketer</position>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="e2" level="l1">
        <First>Jane</First>
        <Dep code="Marketing"></Dep>
        <position>Marketer</position>
    </Employee>
    <Boss id="e3" level="l2">
        <First>Ben</First>
        <Dep code="Marketing"></Dep>
    </Boss>
</Company>
```

Of course there can be many more employees and departments.
I need to copy the position element from the Department to each of the Employees that work in the Department (e.g. for Marketing have `<Dep code="Marketing">`), but **not to the Bosses**. The department can be checked using its `id` attribute or `depName` element, they should be identical.

I'm new to an XSLT so just have a basic idea how to select the element but don't really know how to go on from here (copy it to the correct place):

```
<xsl:template match="Department">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="position"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Edit: Added attributes to employees, they need to be retained in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a key

```
<xsl:key name="dep" match="Department" use="@id"/>
```

and then write the template for `Employee`

```
<xsl:template match="Employee">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*, node(), key('dep', Dep/@code)/position"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The comma operator `,` is availble with XSLT 2 or 3 processors, for an XSLT 1 processor use two separate

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="key('dep', Dep/@code)/position"/>
```

Comment: Small addition - Employees also have attributes that need to be retained, copying the position works but the attributes of the Employees are deleted. Can you please take a look?
Edit - Digging through other StackOverflow answers looks like it works when adding '<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>' before the copy-of comands. Please add it and I will accept the answer